# Can I enter data into an Excel cell as a formula, but keep only the resulting value?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have data to enter into cells that is the result of some basic addition. Rather than screwing up the addition in my head, I'd like to just type the addition into a cell, but without keeping the formula.

So, is there a way to type <kbd>9+9</kbd> into a cell, and have the cell's contents be "18" and NOT "9+9," NOR "=sum(9+9)?"

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vba.  Using a Worksheet_Change event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo cleanup
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Value = Me.Evaluate(Target.Value)
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

cleanup:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Put this in the worksheet code of the worksheet you want.  Change the Intersect Range("A:A") to that of the cells in which you want it to fire.

As is, If I type `9+9` in A1 it replaces it with `18`.

Comment: This is good, and is probably the right answer... but it's really more work than this particular task deserves ;-) And I'm not sure I'm allowed to add code to this spreadsheet... It's worth keeping for future knowledge, though.

Comment: @mHurley There really is no way to do what you request.  Function by their nature can return a value to the cell from where they are called but not replace the value in those cells or any other.  I hope you find your answer but in my opinion, there is no direct answer to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (on a cell or a whole range) a `<COPY>` and then directly `<PASTE VALUES>`; that will overwrite all formulas with their results. That is a separate step though; best done after you entered all your `=x+y` formulas.

Excel recognizes some input as what you intended, for example if you type `1/2<RET>`, it will enter 0.5 in the cell. That only works for divisions, though.

Comment: This is good information, but adds work rather than reducing it ;-)